# ¿Cuál es el origen de "merendola"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

La palabra *merendola* es de esas que hace gracia simplemente cómo suena. Según la RAE:

> **[merendola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P02hgVd)**
>
> 1. f. Merienda espléndida y abundante.

Un ejemplo de uso:

> *Por ejemplo, uno de mis amigos, que prepara actualmente una novela de asunto andaluz, se halla preocupado por una verdadera nonada. Una de las escenas capitales de su narración es una merendola campestre, y mi amigo no sabe bajo qué árbol cobijar a sus personajes.*
>
> Emilio García Gómez, "Nuevas escenas andaluzas", 1948 (España)

Por el significado de la palabra, se diría que "merendola" debería ser un aumentativo de merienda, pero el sufijo *-ola* no lo recoge el diccionario (como sí sucede con otros sufijos aumentativos como *[-ón, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R3Ff5cR)*).

Por tanto, y dado que el diccionario no se atreve a aventurar la etimología de *merendola* (aunque parece casi seguro que es una variación de *merienda*), ¿cuál podría ser el origen de tan simpática palabra?

Comment: Tenemos también ["merendona"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P055lY6) donde se usa el sufijo -on,na como dices (aumentativo). Yo entiendo que el sufijo _-ol, ola_ funciona distinto (faro --> farol y farola). El caso de _merendola_ debe ser particular. Lo mismo es origen no tiene uso aumentativo ni diminutivo, y está formado un poco de casualidad, com algunos gentilicios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las fuentes que pude consultar sugieren que proviene del aragonés: por ejemplo, el artículo ["Aragonesismos en el andaluz oriental"](http://ifc.dpz.es/recursos/publicaciones/01/12/4salvador.pdf), de Gregorio Salvador (1953) indica

> merendola, 'merendona' (Borao). El DRAE la da como de Aragón y Murcia
>   y para esta región la documenta G. Soriano § 65₂. También en Álava
>   (Baráibar) y en Maragatería y Astorga (Garrote). En Cúllar es la forma
>   usual, pero más al Sur parece que predomina *merendona*.

(En efecto, "merendola" figura en el [*Diccionario de voces aragonesas*](https://archive.org/stream/diccionariodevoc00borauoft#page/266/mode/2up/search/merendola) de Gerónimo Borao allí citado y, también, la edición 1947 del DRAE, consultada en el [*Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico*](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), señala que la expresión es de uso en Aragón y Murcia.)

En cuanto a la diferenciación de sonidos, otro artículo, "Caracterización lingüística del habla de Villena (Alicante)", de José Fernando Domene Verdú ([*Archivo de filología aragonesa*](http://ifc.dpz.es/recursos/publicaciones/30/65/_ebook.pdf), 2010) menciona:

> La disimilación se manifiesta en la pérdida de la consonante líquida
>   de la sílaba inicial, igual que en otros dialectos (*pograma <
>   programa*, *poblema < problema*, *pogreso < progreso* y *poclama <
>   proclama*) y en el cambio fonético *n > l* en la palabra *merendola <
>   merendona*, común también al catalán, aragonés y murciano.

Answer (score 1):

**-olo, -ola**

Sufijo de origen unas veces culto, otras catalán o gallego. Forma sustantivos generalmente de significación diminutiva, por ejemplo *arteriola* o *banderola*.

Los masculinos se apocopan casi todos en -ol (por ejemplo *farol*), pero no siempre (por ejemplo, *bronquiolo*)